# How can we read variables from file and use them in promql query?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana, promql

I have configured [docker container and host dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/395-main-overview/) in grafana. By default it shows data for all docker containers:

[image]

Note that their are two docker stacks / swarms: `xyz_stack_1` and `xyz_stack_1_monitoring`. `xyz_stack` is docker swarm of my react web app while `xyz_stack_monitoring` is docker swarm of monitoring the web app and it contains prometheus, grafana, node exporter and cadvisor. As it can be seen, the panel shows information about containers from both swarms.

Now, I have embedded this panel in my react web app and obviously it also shows all docker containers from both swarms. I need to put a toggle button in my web app, so that it will allow toggling between information of just `xyz_stack_1` or both swarms (above panel).

Promql query of above panel is:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name=~".+"}[$interval])) by (name) * 100
```

For panel containing information of just `xyz_stack_1` containers, I can duplicate the panel and change its query to:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_com_docker_stack_namespace="xyz_stack_1"}[$interval])) by (name) * 100
```

I tested this query in grafana and it works as intended.

Now on toggle click, I can show / hide panels.

However I am not able to figure it out, how can I feed the string `xyz_stack_1` to grafana. I have setup [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file to start up all the containers. The configuration is done through [prometheus.yaml](https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/blob/master/prometheus/prometheus.yml), [grafana.ini](https://github.com/kubeflow/community/blob/master/devstats/config/grafana/etc/grafana.ini.example), [dashboards.yaml](https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/blob/master/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboard.yml) and [datasources.yaml](https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/blob/master/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml)

My guessing is that I will set variable with value `xyz-stack-1` in some of these files and refer in grafana dashboard promql query. But how do I exactly do this? Am quite new to prometheus, grafana and promql.

PS: above various yaml and ini file links are for example. These are not exactly my files. But I follow similar appoach.

Comment: Create two separate panels: one with all stacks, and one with a single one. Once user pushes toggle button, switch iframe link from one panel to another.

Comment: But I will not be knowing the name of specific docker stack corresponding to web app. Someone may change the name of the stack while running `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml <my-docker-stack>`. We have many different clients for out app. In that case we need option to pass some initialisation variable.

Comment: I asked bing chat "how can I read variables from text files in grafana?". It says: Create a new data source of type “File”... While chatgot say: You can do this by going to the Plugins section in the Grafana UI, searching for "Text File" in the plugin list, and installing/activating the plugin. But I guess none of them exist right?

Comment: It feels like you mixed everything up (or I don't understand what you want to achieve). You need to read file in your react app, not grafana. If you need to pass variable, you can do so by passing parameter into iframe query in format `var-name_of_variable=value_of_variable`. You can see example of something like this [here](https://play.grafana.org/d/Gs2NBKkGk/variable-format-doublequote?orgId=1)

Answer (score 0):

I created dashboard "Custom" variable `app_stack_name` with single value `xyz_stack_1`,  used it in promql:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_com_docker_stack_namespace="$app_stack_name"}[$interval])) by (name) * 100
```

exported dashboard json file and put it in dashboards directory so that this pre-configured dashboard will get provisioned automatically. If someone changes the stack name from `xyz_stack_1` to say `abc_stack_1`, one has to replace all instances of `xyz_stack_1` with `abc_stack_1` in json file and then restart grafana container.